# Splitting array of objects into multiple array containing object with same value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

So I have an array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: 'Mike Doe',
    age: 21
  },
  {
    name: 'Joe Doe',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: 'Ted Doe',
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: 'Jay Doe',
    age: 22
  }
]
```

and I need to split this into multiple arrays of the objects with the same age, so the output would look like this:

```
arr1 = [
  {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: 'Ted Doe',
    age: 23
  }
]

arr2 = [
  {
    name: 'Jane Doe',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: 'Joe Doe',
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: 'Jay Doe',
    age: 22
  }
]

arr3 = [
  {
    name: 'Mike Doe',
    age: 21
  }
]
```

The ages could be anything and there could end up being around 100 objects in the array at the time of sorting so I don't think a loop would be the best way, but I don't know. And if a loop is the answer I don't know how I would write it because the ages will not always be 21,22,23 , they could be any numbers

Comment: Do you really need dynamic variables? It would be easier if you created a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: @Barmar Could you explain this idea? I might be able to adapt if this will work another way. At the moment I found a function in the underscore package called groupBy which does exactly what I need, but i'd rather not rely on an entire package for a single function.